# How to make a script to launch different scripts in different workspaces in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal

I have limited access to a linux machine, meaning I cannot install any external tools. I want to make a script to open terminals with ssh at different workspaces. However, I found that one way to move the terminals is to use `wmctrl` which I cannot install. Another approach was to use `xdotool` but I also cannot use it.

The only solution I see is to make a script that calls opens a terminal in the different workspaces and run something different in each of them. Is that the solution or there is anything else I could try?

This is the code I have now

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define your SSH sessions
sessions=("user@host1" "user@host2" "user@host3")

# Define the workspace numbers for each SSH session
workspaces=(1 2 3)

# Open terminals for each SSH session and move them to respective workspaces
for ((i=0; i<${#sessions[@]}; i++)); do
    gnome-terminal --tab --title="${sessions[i]}" -- bash -c "ssh ${sessions[i]}; exec bash" &
    sleep 2  # Adjust sleep time as needed to ensure terminals open properly
done
```